# Entity Framework 6 Model From Database - Disable Automatic Association Creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an EF model with all associations / table relationships deleted, but every time I "update model from database" all of the associations return.  I would like a flat model, with no relationships, and don't want to have to delete the associations each time I refresh the model.  When you first create the model from the DB, you can choose to ignore FK relationships, but regardless of this setting, future updates of the model bring the associations back.

Comment: *** I should add, switching to code first is not feasible due to the size and complexity of this model.

Comment: Why do you have relationships but don't want them? What is the problem when you have the navigation properties?

Comment: This is for a large legacy application that, unfortunately, has a lot of inheritance and overlaying partial classes that have specialized collections of child objects and not the standard ICollection.  Additionally, there are overrides on the constructors, etc. If all associations are removed, we don't have any conflicts with migrating from Linq-To-SQL to EF.

Comment: Can you edit the T4 template (the `.tt` file) and remove the generation of the navigation properties?

Comment: Yes, but the EDMX still has references to the Foreign Keys which causes DB calls to error and it's not helpful to remove all of them from the EDMX because they just return after a refresh.

Comment: When you remove the generation of the navigation properties from the T4 template, rebuild your project and do a test run, what errors do you get on your DB calls you have mentioned? The navigation properties shouldn't "return" when you update the model because the T4 template will not be changed.

Comment: One example, but this happens for all relationships:Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The relationship 'MyModel.FK_MyKey' was not loaded because the type 'MyModel.SomeProperty' is not available.
The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:
The required property 'MyProperty' does not exist on the type 'MyProject.MyTable'.

Comment: Also, it's frustrating because VS didn't add the relationships initially and we did our complete migration.  Then, once merged over to the Trunk, it started adding them any time we updated the model.

Comment: Hack idea.  Restore a database (from DDL?) and then drop all the FK's and then run the tool.

Comment: @NickLeuchtenberg Other solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907185/prevent-ef6-from-generate-navigation-properties are not working? Please provide some kind of [mcve] with the problem you have, the attempts you have made and the error messages you get and/or the problems you have for each attempt. Also provide the example database structure, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Add all the steps you have tried so we see how you tried them (maybe you did something wrong)

Comment: @Progman - No, that solution example is not referring to T4 - as it doesn't user MetadataLoader, but uses EdmMetadataLoader - I think it might have something to do with that.  Need to figure out how to load from the Store Model instead of Conceptual Model (EDMX) for T4.